# How to draw to an NSView graphics context from inside a CVDisplayLink callback?

Tags: cocoa, macos, quartz-2d

I have a simple game that renders 2D graphics to a frame buffer (not using any OpenGL). I was going to use a CVDisplayLink to get a clean framerate, however most examples on the web deal with OpenGL or QuickTime.

So far I have a sub class of NSView:

```
@interface GameView : NSView {
@private
    CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink;
}

- (CVReturn)getFrameForTime:(const CVTimeStamp*)outputTime;
@end
```

And I set up the CVDisplayLink callback:

```
CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(displayLink, MyDisplayLinkCallback, self);
```

And I have the callback function:

```
CVReturn MyDisplayLinkCallback (CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink,
                                const CVTimeStamp *inNow,
                                const CVTimeStamp *inOutputTime,
                                CVOptionFlags flagsIn,
                                CVOptionFlags *flagsOut,
                                void *displayLinkContext)
{
    CVReturn error = [(GameView*)displayLinkContext getFrameForTime:inOutputTime];

    return error;
}
```

The part where I'm stuck is what to do in `getFrameForTime:` to draw to the graphics context in the GameView. My first guess was to do the drawing the same way you would in `drawRect:`

```
- (CVReturn)getFrameForTime:(const CVTimeStamp*)outputTime
{
    CGContextRef ctxCurrent = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];

    //.. Drawing code follows
}
```

But `ctxCurrent` is `nil` which I think I understand - normally there is some setup that happens before the `drawRect:` that makes your view the current context. I think this is the part I'm missing. How do I get the context for my view?

Or am I going about this in all the wrong ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could leave your drawing code in `‑drawRect:` and then in your `MyDisplayLinkCallback()` set an ivar to the current time and call `‑display` on your view. This will force your view to immediately redraw itself.

In your `‑drawRect:` method, just use the value of the time ivar to do whatever drawing is necessary to update the view appropriately for the current animation frame.

Comment: Thanks, this is working and seems to be the cleanest I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate `-draw:` method, and call that from your `MyDisplayLinkCallback()` as well as from `-drawRect:`.

I found Rob Keniger's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6405528) to my liking and tried it out; sadly, if you call `-display` from your display link callback your app may hang in a deadlock when you terminate the app, leaving you to force-quit the app (for me it happened more often than not).

Comment: Please add a link to Rob Keniger's response. It would be pretty interesting to see that.

Comment: @SalmonKiller: How do I link? It's the currently accepted answer just above mine.